# Google API Gmail error 500 Internal error encountered

Tags: api, gmail

I try send request https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/ using Postman, but I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Internal error encountered.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "backendError"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INTERNAL"
    }
}
```

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this tool[1] to check your domain, most likely there are some critical problems detected within this domain. Mail-flow is probably affected.

Also check this documentation[2] on domain nameservers.

[1]https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/

[2]https://support.google.com/a/answer/2573637#H